# HTML5 CSS equal height columns not working with images [Table/Table Cell Method]

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to figure out how to make equal column heights using HTML and CSS only. The method i'm trying to use is the setting the containing element to display table and the columns to display table-cell.

It works very well when there is text only in the columns. But if I add an image to one of the columns then it breaks. It looks like it adds massive padding above or below the elements in either column.

How do I fix this so that I have one column with text and the second column with the image. Columns with the elements aligned to the top of their container? IM STUCK :-(

See examples:

Two Columns Text Only: https://jsfiddle.net/acekicker77/gowcsx0c/

Two Columns with Image: https://jsfiddle.net/acekicker77/mqojn2kx/

**HTML 2:**

```css
main {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 1em;
}

#colWrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: brown;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0;
}

.imgWrap {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="colWrap">
    <div class="col">
      <p>This is a column of text</p>
    </div>
    <!-- close div class col -->

    <div class="col">
      <p>This is a column of text</p>
      <p>This column is longer than the other</p>
    </div>
    <!-- close div class col -->
  </div>
<!-- close id colWrap -->
</main>
```

Comment: There's not the fiddle with the image example :)

Comment: There's no image in the second fiddle. Please update the fiddle

Comment: What do you want the width of the image to be 100% of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `vertical-align:top` for align element on top of div

```css
main {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 1em;
}

#colWrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: brown;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align:top; 
}

.imgWrap {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="colWrap">
    <div class="col">
      <p>This is a column of text</p>
    </div>
    <!-- close div class col -->

    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://imageshack.com/i/povCNXlyj"/>
      <p>This is a column of text</p>
      <p>This column is longer than the other</p>
    </div>
    <!-- close div class col -->

  </div>
  <!-- close id colWrap -->

</main>
<!--close main content -->
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use in .col class vertical-align: middle;

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/qntmrbn1/) Add a vertical align middle to your table-cell element that will ensure your image is aligned

```
vertical-align: middle;
```